# Facebook app settings page

Tags: facebook, startup

On this page
Step 1: Create a Facebook App

To create a Facebook app, go to the Developer App, click the 'Create New App' button, and enter your app name and a namespace to get started.

I go back to my FB page. How do I get to the Apps setting page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps and then find your application in the list on the left side.

Comment: I don't have an app, trying to create one. On this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#create-app) page` I click on "Developer App" and am directed to my FB page not to Developer Apps as advertised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are attempting to create an application using your Page user.  (logging in as your page).  This is not possible.
You must use your personal account to create an application. You can not use the user of your page.

This is so that Facebook will be able to "track" the administrators of applications back to "real people" in the event that the application is found to be violating Facebook's Terms of Service.